# Receive a memory pressure event with cgroups v2 when no memory limit is set

Tags: linux, cgroups, out-of-memory

With cgroups v1, it is possible to listen for events about memory pressure. According to the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt), one needs to

- Create a new `eventfd`
- Open `memory.pressure_level` for reading
- Open `cgroup.event_control` for writing
- Write `{eventfd} {pressure_level_fd} {level}` (where `level` is `low`, `medium`, or `critical`) to `event_control`
- Wait until reading from the eventfd returns 8 bytes

When doing so with a program that's about to run out of memory, you'll receive a long train of `low` events, then a few `medium` and `critical`, before finally the OOM killer will run.
If you want to convince yourself of this, I've prepared a [little Rust example](https://gist.github.com/jcaesar/2905b680aa71e971cebbbbf8d601a3d5#file-cv1-rs), you can execute it with `cargo build --release --examples && sudo target/release/examples/cv1`.

For cgroups v2 ([docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt)), similar events can be received by

- Setting up an inotify watch on `memory.events.local`
- Reading and parsing the file fully, comparing numbers after each event received

This works (even without root, unlike v1), when setting a memory limit in the cgroup, and you'll usually receive at least a few inotify events with increases either in `high` or `max`. (Again, if you want to convince yourself of this, run `systemd-run --same-dir --pty --user -p MemoryMax=1G cargo run --example cv2` on the above gist.)

However, when there's no memory limit set, or the limit is higher than the available memory, the process will be killed without events received. Looking at `memory.pressure` shows a strong increase, so the kernel definitely knows that something is up before it invokes the OOM killer. Is there a way to get it to tell us, with a nice behavior like cgroups v1 that gives lots of warnings up ahead?

Note: I'm aware of some related questions ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362833/how-to-trigger-action-on-low-memory-condition-in-linux/), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172559/receive-signal-before-process-is-being-killed-by-oom-killer-cgroups)), but:

- They're old and questions/answers only consider cgroups v1
- I'd like to be triggered before the oom killer becomes active, so that hack with "spawning a high oom_score_adj canary process" is out.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the [docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/accounting/psi.html) a bit more carefully, I found an answer. To summarize, you can watch for memory pressure by writing `some 50000 2000000\0` to an fd of `/proc/pressure/memory` and then polling the fd for `PRI` events.

I'm not marking it as accepted, since I'm not happy with it:

- The cgroups-based variant of this (at `$CGROUP_FS/$GROUP/memory.pressure`) is only available to root - if you use the global variant at `/proc/pressure/`, you might receive events even though your process still has lots of memory available.
- The minimum interval for non-root users is 2 seconds - on systems without swap, this means that you might get OOM-killed before the first event.